# Error:Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found. on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv, kotlin

I get this error when I add this to Android Studio

```
"Error:Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.".
```

I am trying to install opencv on my android, but it will not work.
I made a new project in my Android that is empty but works

My build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

def openCVersionName = "4.5.4"
def openCVersionCode = ((4 * 100 + 5) * 100 + 4) * 10 + 0

println "OpenCV: " +openCVersionName + " " + project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26

    versionCode openCVersionCode
    versionName openCVersionName

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            targets "opencv_jni_shared"
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        packagingOptions {
            doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
        }
    }
    release {
        packagingOptions {
            doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
        java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['java/src']
        res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
        manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path (project.projectDir.toString() + '/libcxx_helper/CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}
}

dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same error with Android Studio 2020.3.1 and fixed the error by adding  this on top of the skd's build gradle (above 'apply plugin...'):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.4.0"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify ``Exactly`` what file to add this to.

Comment: @Mich This should be added to top level build.gradle